# Enchant does not works

Tags: php, enchant

I placed `fa_IR.dic` and `fa_IR.aff` files in `d:/fa` and runned:

```
<?php
$r = enchant_broker_init();
enchant_broker_set_dict_path($r, ENCHANT_ISPELL, 'd:/fa');
var_dump($d = enchant_broker_request_dict($r, 'fa_IR'));
var_dump(enchant_broker_get_dict_path($r, ENCHANT_ISPELL));

//bool(false)
//string(5) "d:/fa"
```

But `enchant_broker_request_dict` return `false`. What is wrong? I am using PHP5.5 on Windows.

Comment: Have you uncomment `extension=php_enchant.dll` line in php.ini? it is necessary. If not then do.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ Yes, I did.

Comment: Here is the full documentation: http://in3.php.net/enchant